# Golang: How to install official Go fonts for Golang developement

Tags: go, fonts, go-font

Go recently announced Go font most suitable for go development.

https://blog.golang.org/go-fonts blog post has some details about it.

However it is not very clear to me how to install them in my mac to use them in Go development. Can anyone help me out here please.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

1. Download official fonts https://go.googlesource.com/image/+archive/master/font/gofont/ttfs.tar.gz
2. Extract font files

> tar -xvzf image-master-font-gofont-ttfs.tar.gz

3. Click on ttf file to install respective font. In Mac, Font Book will open by default. Ubuntu has font application too. Click on install. After installing all the go font variants, Font Book will look like following.

[image: Go Fonts]

4. Go to your favorite Go editor and assign Go font for go files.

   In Sublime Text, Changing the font can be done via adding these lines to the right-hand pane of <kbd>Preferences ▸ Settings</kbd>:

   > "font_face": "Go Mono",
   >
   > "font_size": 10

Bonus Tip: Use Go Mono font. Go code looks awesome in it.

Answer (score 4):

This may already be answered, but if you are on a metered connection (or are low on disk space) and don't want the entire repo cloned at this time, you can also go to `https://go.googlesource.com/image/+/master/font/gofont/ttfs/` and click the tgz option.  Then you get a tgz of just the TTFs.